# Print the comment form with PHP

Tags: 7, forms, comments

I'm trying to print a comment form with the following code.

```
<?php 
    print drupal_get_form('comment_form', array('nid' => $row->nid), t('Post new comment')); 
?>
```

All I get is the following error repeated 40 times:

> Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in comment_form() (line 1845 of /home/admin/public_html/website.com/modules/comment/comment.module).`

The comment form is called from inside a [PHP Views](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) field. What is the proper way to add a comment for to a node in Drupal 7?

There are actually a lot more errors, most of which repeat at least once:

> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type comment. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7501 of /home/admin/public_html/website.com/includes/common.inc).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form() (line 1854 of /home/admin/public_html/website.com/modules/comment/comment.module).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`comment_form()` is expecting the parameter to be an object rather than an array so you should be doing something like this:

```
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
```

Note the lack of a 3rd parameter passed to `drupal_get_form()`, `comment_form()` only accepts the comment as a parameter, if you want to add a title you'll have to print that separately.

Finally `drupal_get_form()` returns a render array rather than a string so you need to pass it through the [`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) function:

```
print render($form);
```

The extra errors you're getting are just side-effects of passing an array rather than an object to the `comment_form()` function.

Comment: Thanks man... some of this documentation is rather cryptic