# D7 comment form doesn't submit

Tags: 7, forms, comments

I've successfully printed a comment form on a views-built page using a PHP Views field (as found in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/d7-print-comment-form-with-php)). The form doesn't submit right away though - instead of submitting, the comment "save" button redirects to the "comment/reply/[nid]" page with blank values.

Comment form print code:

```
$comment = new stdClass;
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
print render($form);
```

Are there extra details that should be added to the $comment object before or during the `drupal_get_form()` or `render()` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next:

```
// ...
$comment->nid = $row->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment);
$form['#redirect'] = 'CHANGE_VIEWSPAGE_HERE?page=' . (int)$_GET['page'];
print render($form);
```

Comment: Nice work. What's the difference between setting ?page and ?destination ?

Comment: ?page mean that after submission comment, you form return to views with certain page number (if it's pagered), so user will not move across pages again after submission...